# Time between to nucleus to explode

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

From the position of a non-moving observer, two nucleus A and B are moving with relative velocity $u_{a}=ac$ and $u_{b}=bc$ where, $a,b$ constants that $0<a<b<1$ and $c$ the speed of light.
Observer O found that after time $t$, the two nucleus expode simultaneously. Which is the time lapse between the explosion of B from the nucleus A?

MY solution:
The velocity of B from observer A is $\frac{u_{A}+u_{B}}{1+\frac{u_{A}u_{B}}{c^2}}=\frac{a+b}{1+ab}$.

Time in the system of A from observer O is $$t_{A}=\frac{t-u_{A}c}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u_{A}^2}{c}}}=\frac{t-a^2t}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}=t\sqrt{1-a^2}$$

The distance between A and B is $x=u_{B,A}\cdot t=\frac{a+b}{1+ab}ct$,
so the time of the B explosion from A is $$\frac{t_{a}-u_{B,A}t_{a}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u_{B,A}^2}{c^2}}}=\frac{1-\frac{a+b}{1+ab}a}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{a+b}{1+ab})^{2}}}\sqrt{1-a^2}t$$.
I want to ask if my proof is correct, since I am new to Special Relativity Theory (as a 19-year old electrical engineering student).
Any answer or comment that helps would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your solution is wrong. Take for example that observer A Is not moving, which means that $a=0$. Then observer A and O should measure both a timelapse $\Delta t_O=\Delta t_A=0$ but in your expression $\Delta t_A \neq 0$ for $a=0$.

Comment: @ΜπαμπηςΠοζουκιδης Yes, unfortunately my fears that I did something wrong came true. However, could you give me an idea on to approach this problem?

Comment: Since you know both the spatial separation and the time separation in reference frame $O$, the Lorentz transformation $\Delta t^{\prime}=\gamma\left(\Delta t-\frac{v \Delta x}{c^{2}}\right)$ can give you the time separation in reference frame $A$.